# Refresh page directing it to a particular div using HTML5/CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple website and I am encountering a problem whenever I reload it.

I placed my menu at the middle of the screen and when you clicked it, it needs to go down to the content. My problem is, whenever I reload it, it would still go up and show the upper picture. What I want is that after one of the menu is pressed, the menu should now stay on the upper corner of the screen without showing the upper picture (Sample website -> http://ec2-54-84-168-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com/Teapop/)

It seems like my url code that directs it on a particular div (e.g menu#teapop_nav)` doesn't work as I expected after I deployed it on the hosting site even though it works well on my local build.

Without using any javascript code, is there a fix for this using html5/css3?

Thank you.

Comment: The only way I can think of accomplishing this is removing the #teapop_nav thingys at the end of the url once the load has completed, so that on reload, it doesn't redirect to the div, but this, as far as I know, can only be done using javascript

Comment: As you said it works perfectly in your local system, I feel there is something to do with the page size.

Answer (score 0):

i just tested it on my computer (chrome & firefox) and it seems to work. And also on page refresh. The picture is always on the top.

Comment: That's interesting because I was just on it in Chrome, and it always redirected to the content below the image when reloading or refreshing the page

Comment: yes. but when u reload it, it always show the upper picture (girl) first like there's an animation to it then the page goes down until it reaches the menu as the top o f the page...  what i want it to show starting from the menu and not from the upper picture(girl).